# Two type of Login - One System Integrate (MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing an application which consists of two types of admission, one for employees of the company that must manage administrative elements and the other should be for users who need to make a purchase in the company, what solution should implement for the kind of access? because access of administrative employees is done, thanks.

PD: Users should not see the menus administrative staff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have different roles for each user type. Also have two different master page, one for administration one for users. All your administration related modules must use administration master page (this will have all administration related menus) and general user module must use user master page. After login according to their role type redirect to respective action methods.

Comment: The best approach... I override my class for roles, I did not know about several layout in a single project, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the same authentication layer for both types of users?  If so, implement Role Based Access Control (RBAC) -- [here's a link to a relevant MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z164t8hs(v=vs.110).aspx).

If you're not using the same authentication system, then the admin interface should be a separate application than the user system; consider implementing both as "microservices" that share some portion of a persistence layer.  Or have the admin app act through an API on the primary application.

Comment: The admin interface create the user login for purchase, the system send the pass for email and sms to the user, when the user want to purchase the product, access to the system with that login create, I think that a diferent layer but the same db.